# Origin of "happen"

Tags: etymology, verbs, british-english

What is the origin of the word *happen*? If it comes from the word *hap*, what is the early usage of that word?

Comment: Why is this marked British English? Also, what dictionaries have you consulted?

Comment: See the [online etymological dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=happen&searchmode=none) for initial self-researched answers to such basic questions. Then come back and ask a question about what you didn't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, certainly *happen* comes from *hap*.  Its earliest citations are only from the late 14<sup>th</sup> century. The OED reports that *happen* is from Middle English, and that is either from  *hap* the noun, or as an extended form of *hap* the verb.

Here is an abbreviated set of their definitions and citations for *hap* the verb,  which are “early” compared to our present era, but still recent enough to still make sense:

> 1. *intr*. To come about by ‘hap’ or chance; to happen, come to pass, occur, chance. **a.** with the event expressed either by a sb. or pron. preceding the verb as subject, or by a clause or infinitive following it, the verb being then generally preceded by it. Formerly with auxiliary *be* instead of *have*.
>
>    - 1596 Shaks. *Tam. Shr.* ɪᴠ. iv. 107 ― Then wherefore should I doubt: Hap what hap may, Ile roundly goe about her.
>    - A. 1677 Barrow *Serm. Wks.* 1716 I. 22 ― What can hap to him worthy to be deemed evil?
>    - 1808 Scott *Marm*. ɪɪɪ. xiv, ― Thus oft it haps, that··A feather daunts the brave.
>    - 1880 Tennyson *Battle Brunanburh* xᴠ, ― Never had huger Slaughter of heroes··Hapt in this isle.
> 2. To have the hap, fortune, or luck (*to do* something, or with clause).
>
>    - 1814 Scott *Ld. of Isles* ɪɪɪ. xiii, ― Where’er I happ’d to roam.
> 3. To come or go by chance; to light or chance on or upon. Cf. **happen** *v*. <sup>4</sup>.
>
>    - 1718 Bp. Hutchinson *Witchcraft* xᴠ. (1720) 168 ― He chanced to hap upon a Boy.
>    - 1762 Foote *Orators* ɪɪ. Wks. 1799 I. 217 ― Was it yourself that was happing about here but now?
>    - 1863 A. B. Grosart *Small Sins* Pref. Note (ed. 2) 14 ― [This book] I have not been fortunate enough to hap upon.

Comment: According to American Heritage, it comes (like _hap, hapless, happy,_ and _mishap_) from the PIE root _*kob-_ 'to suit, fit, succeed'.

Comment: @JohnLawler That reminds me, do you happen to know a sound law that explains *cornu > horn* the way you see there?

Comment: [**Grimm's Law**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/GrimmsLaw.pdf) works [like this](http://kmcgowan.rice.edu/wow/grimm/), and has [these cognates](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/GrimmsLawCognates.pdf), among others.